# Choosing between First-Differences and Fixed Effects (Within estimator) - arguments in favour of FD

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, fixed-effects-model, trend

First of all, I'd like to say I have read the standard econometric textbook sections on FE vs FD.  Therefore, I am familiar with the relative efficiency of each of the methods depending on the assumptions on the serial correlation of the errors.

However, I have been suggested by my professor to estimate my FE model using FD but do not find any valid arguments for using one vs the other.

I am investigating the effect of drought shocks on agriculture production as well as on GDP using panel data for 120 countries for a time span of around 40 years.   The drought shocks are measured by a dummy variable that switches on if a country experiences drought.  There are time-fixed effects, country-fixed effects, and country-specific time trends.
My model looks as follows in levels:

[image]

and like this in FD:

[image]

I am looking for arguments to go with the First Differenced regression rather than the regression in levels:

Some aspects I've considered are:

- Serial correlation and relative efficiency issues.
- Convenient interpretation of effect on growth rates
- Can estimating both FD and FE serve as some kind of robustness test if estimated coefficients BETA are similar?
- Considering drought is assumed to be transitory and contemporaneous, meaning the effect of the dummy being equal to 1 will be immediately translated to dependent variable effect will not have lagged effects.

I am really struggling to find strong arguments for FD.  If anyone has any comments or suggestions they would be very welcome.